# Could MH370 happen again today?

Tags: accidents, accident-investigation

This month being the 10th anniversary of the tragedy that shocked the world, Malaysia Airlines Flight 370, I wonder if this could happen again today.

Can I pilot of a airliner make an airplane "disappear" and make it impossible for recovery?

I can't recall any new changes that were implemented after the tragedy, were there any?

Comment: *I can't recall any new changes that were implemented after the tragedy, were there any?* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370#Air_transport_industry The Wikipedia page has it neatly summarized for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question literally because it's not changes that were *implemented* but rather changes that "just happened", but the price of building satellites has dropped significantly since then, as has the price of operating satellites, and most dramatically, the price of launching satellites has come way down. The number of active, operational satellites in space has increased by a factor of 7.5 between 2014 and now and is only going to grow.

Comment: Of the ~17000 objects that have been launched into space by all of humanity combined in the last 66 years, almost half have been launched in the last 4 years. And one fourth of all satellites launched in the history of humankind are Starlink satellites, which enable high-bandwidth, low-latency, reliable data communication everywhere on Earth – something that simply did not exist 10 years ago. And they're not the only ones, there's OneWeb, Project Kuiper, two private and one military Chinese network, Starshield, …

Comment: All of these are significant changes, but none of them have been implemented. They just happened.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, it doesn't answer the question because it isn't an answer... it's a comment.  Anyway, Sanchises didn't claim that the changes came about as a direct result of this flight, only that changes have occurred.  It was simply an offer of information.  Oh yeah, and satellite launches don't "*just happen*"!

Comment: "*Space-Based ADS-B: No longer a concept, but an operational reality*" by [Aireon](https://aireon.com/space-based-ads-b-no-longer-concept-operational-reality/). Apparently they have a [contract with Eurocontrol](https://www.atc-network.com/atc-news/aireon-llc-and-eurocontrol/integrating-aireons-space-based-ads-b-into-eurocontrols-network-operations-system-brings-major-predictability-gains-and-will-unlock-future-capacity). They seem to use the [Iridium constellation](https://www.atc-network.com/atc-news/aireon-llc/aireon-announces-successful-first-launch-for-space-based-ads-b-network).

Comment: @mins Space-Based ADS-B is pretty interesting, especially for oceanic airspace, but it won't help when the transponder is intentionally turned off like it was on MH370.

Comment: @Bianfable: Space ADS-B is a required condition to save lives and spare money/time in avoidable SAR (AF447). This condition is going to be a reality (the data volume is very low, not a concern for satcoms), but is not sufficient. It's more than urgent for the regulating agencies to make crews admit the necessity to remove the possibility for them to disconnect safety devices. Technically it is a trivial change, and there is no valid excuse. A lot of electrical devices cannot be disconnected already (e.g. the ELT).

Comment: so from what I read, that means technically, as of today, the same thing can happen again?

Comment: @Gabe: Can this happen again? It depends on what you put behind "this", we are still reduced to conjectures.. ADS-B, ACARS  and radar contact could still be lost over ocean. Nothing indicates events like switching off radio signals are deliberate actions.The scenario of a lithium fire followed by a depressurization and/or general hypoxia is one of a few credible scenarios. On the changes side, it is possible MA has now subscribed for a satellite link for ACARS on all of its aircraft flying over the ocean. If this is the case, ACARS may be sufficient to locate the plane.

Comment: @mins - other scenarios maybe are technically possible, but the circumstantial evidence surrounding the turnaround seems just short of conclusive that it was likely intentional. Mentour Pilot recently posted an interesting [video](https://youtu.be/Y5K9HBiJpuk?si=VA63G9tWcuFd9RBD) about it.

Comment: @StevePemberton: I agree, since 2018 and the [investigation report](https://reports.aviation-safety.net/2014/20140308-0_B772_9M-MRO.pdf), it's established the turn at IGARI was made in manual control. That can be criminal or the result of a catastrophic event, without the faintest element in favor of one direction.